# Tabla intermedia y Relaciones Laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel-5

Hola amigos estoy trabajando en un api rest en laravel 5.4 y hasta ahora necesito realizar una relacion entre dos tablas, creando una intermedia. Solo q no estoy seguro si lo estoy haciendo bien y queria su opinion y consejo:
por ejemplo tabla roles:

```
class CreateRolesTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('roles', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('denominacion');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('roles');
    }
}
```

tabla modules:

```
class CreateModulesTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('modules', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('denominacion');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('modules');
    }
}
```

y la tabla intermedia:

```
class CreateRolesModulesTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('roles_modules', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('roles_id')->index();
            $table->integer('modules_id')->index();
            // $table->timestamps();
            });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('roles_modules');
    }
}
```

y la relacion en los modelos, 
modelo roles:
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\modules;

```
class roles extends Model
{
    public function moduls()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('modules');
    }

}
```

Modelo module:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

    use App\roles;

    class modules extends Model
    {
        //
        public function rols(){
            return $this->belongToMany('roles');
        }
}
```

por favor diganme , eso esta bien o como deberia hacerlo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En la migración de la tabla intermedia añadir las **foreign keys**:

```
$table->foreign('roles_id')->references('id')->on('roles');
$table->foreign('modules_id')->references('id')->on('modules');
```

En el modelo **roles**:

```
return $this->belongsToMany(modules::class, 'roles_modules', 'id' /* de roles */, 'id' /* de modules */);
```

En el modelo **modules**:

```
return $this->belongsToMany(roles::class, 'roles_modules', 'id' /* de modules */, 'id' /* de roles */);
```

Si quisieras **obtener campos de la tabla intermedia** sería:

```
return $this->belongsToMany(...)->withPivot('nombreCampo');
```

> Como consejo, en Laravel y muchos otros frameworks y lenguajes de programación 'modernos' aplican el estilo de escritura del código [CamelCase](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase).

Comment: `return $this->belongsToMany(modules::class, 'roles_modules', 'id_roles', 'id_modules');` En el ejemplo que sigues, debería quedar así en los model?

Answer (score -1):

y la tabla intermedia como quedaría definida??

```
return $this->belongsToMany(RolesModules::class, 'roles_modules', 'id_roles', 'id_modules'); ???
```

Comment: Realiza una nueva pregunta basada en [ask], aquí no es visible tu publicación para la comunidad, por lo pronto te sugiero eliminar esta publicación, saludos!